# Adding an image to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to support iOS4 and iOS5. My code works well on iOS4, but don't work on iOS5. How to fix the problem.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"E_44.png"]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(136, 0, 52, 44);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
[imageView release];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Setting custom background for UINavigationBar to support iOS5 and iOS4 too!**

---

As you know, until iOS 5 came out, we used `drawRect` override in `AppDelegate` to customize `UINavigationBar`.
But know, iOS 5 give us some new method for styling (and old doesn’t work).

How to build app that will work on iOS 4 and iOS 5 with stylized `UINavigationBar`?

You must to do both!

In `AppDelegate` use this code:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
[img drawInRect:rect];
}
@end
```

and in `viewDidLoad` method for iOS5 (in your view implementation):

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector( setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]){
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

If you see, here we are asking if navbar will respondToSelector to avoid crash on iOS4!

Answer (score 3):

This doesnt add a background, but this will let you add a image to the Navigation bar

```
 // Create your image<br>
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"yourimage.png"];<br>
 UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

 // set the text view to the image view<br>
 self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Hope this helps.